# HiveQL Inequality Join

Tags: join, hadoop, hive, inequality

I'm aware that Hive for Hadoop does not support inequality joins.  However, I've got a query which seems to run ok.  As to whether the results are correct or not I'm dubious as I had a colleague who I shared this with who found it didn't produce the right result.

Here it is:

```
select foo.id, count(foo.*) as foo_vol, count(bar.*) as bar_vol 
from foo
 left outer outer join bar
  on foo.id = bar.id
  and (bar.f2 in (x, y, z)) = FALSE
group by foo.id
```

Anyone got any ideas on why this explains and runs ok?  Is the issue of inequality joins actually related to whether the criteria uses fields from both sides of the join?  Have FB / apache confirmed that this type of query is going to produce wrong results?

Cheers for any help,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

IN best of my understanding Your query is indeed eque join : foo.id = bar.id 
the condition:  (bar.f2 in (x, y, z)) = FALSE is applied to the bar table only and should not be considered part of the join. 
 
There are no restrictions in hive to put non-equal conditions on table fields.

Comment: Thanks David, yes I see what you mean, since the statement only applies to bar... I guess if the expression was something like foo.id < bar.id that would be an actual inequality join.

Answer (score 0):

Result of outer join in hive is sometimes wrong. I'm working on it.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3381

Comment: Great, thanks Navis.  Btw, I'm using Hive version 0.7.1 and Hadoop 0.20.2 (CDH3)